# Connect a GCP Cloud Function with an instance in a VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I have made a Static VPN connection between an instance on GCP and an instance on AWS.
I can ping from the machine on GCP (10.132.0.2) to the AWS machine (10.16.191.45) and vice versa.

Now I need connect from a Google Cloud Function to the AWS machine.

I have tried to make a VPC Connector, add it in the egress connection settings in the cloud function and add the IP range from the connector (10.130.0.0/28) to the VPN Static Route but when I try to ping the instance in AWS from the Cloud Function always get

`line 45, in connect self._s.connect((host, int(port))) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Here's the code to ping the AWS machine from GCP Cloud Function

```
from tcping import Ping


def hello_world(request):
    # Ping(host, port, timeout)
    ping = Ping('10.132.0.2')
    ping.ping(3)
    return "Done"
```

Any idea how to do it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your VPC Connector in the same VPC as your VPN?

Comment: 1) Connection Refused means that you are talking to something. That error usually means no process is listening on the port number but there was a package exchange with the other TCP stack. 2) Double-check that the IP addresses are correct and that you are actually routing over the VPC. 3) Do not use ping (ICMP) to debug these problems. Use a tool that speaks the same protocol. In your case, you are using TCP, so use a TCP tool.

Comment: VPC connector is in the same VPC as my VPN. Thanks for your suggestions @JohnHanley I will double check and make the changes to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating a Cloud function click “Runtime,build,connection and security settings” choose the “connection” option, make sure under connection that you choose `Allow all traffic` in ingress.

Under connection click `create a serverless VPC connector`. Make sure that Region from Cloud Function is also the same with your VPC connector. Under the network option choose the VPC network where your subnet 10.132.0.2 is located then create an IP range.

Once Serverless VPC connector is created. Refresh the `Network` option in your Cloud Function then choose the name of your VPC connector then click the radio button of `Route all traffic through the VPC connector`.

Just to add up, even if the port is already open in your firewall that doesnt mean that the port is already accessible. You need to make sure that there is a service that is listening so that the port will open, you can check that information on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port#:%7E:text=In%20security%20parlance%2C%20the%20term,is%20called%20a%20closed%20port.).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The problem was in the ports. I have changed the debug to TCP like @johnhanley suggests and checked the ports, changed the tests to the correct ports and it works perfectly.